# How can I see what tier a unit is when producing it?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

Once I've created a new recruit for my army I can see what tier he is. But some upgrades in the cities are for specific tiered units (for example a building that gives all tier 1 and 2 units an extra experience rank).

So how can I see what tier a unit I never produced is? And how can I see what tier a unit that would be unlocked by building something would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change is being added in the [upcoming patch](http://ageofwonders.com/forums/topic/v1-092-huge-beta-patch-available-on-steam/) to address this:

> Added tier level to unit info, allowing preview of the tier level in the city production panel in both the popup and the unit panel.

The patch launches officially next week, but Steam owners can download it as a beta version now.

If you go to the units tab of the Tome of Wonder, and then filter by the race and class of the city you want to build in, it will list all the units that city can (eventually) build. The tier of all these units will be displayed in this list as well. This method isn't ideal, but it's the only method I've managed to find for doing this thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there are any exceptions, but you can tell just about every case by the upkeep value:

- Tier 1: 4gp
- Tier 2: 8gp
- Tier 3: 16gp
- Tier 4: 32gp

(for some creatures, it's mana instead of gold)